# addEventListener to change CSS style for selected id from one class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, addeventlistener

I have many many `img` with the same `class` and proper `id`.

```
<img class="ico" id="n1"></img>
<img class="ico" id="n2"></img>
```

I want to change for example opacity of selected `img` when `mouseover/mouseout`.
I tried with a specified `id` and work:

```
var x = document.getElementById("n1");
x.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ 
    mOverImg(document.getElementById("n1")); });
x.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ mOutImg(document.getElementById("n1")); });

function mOverImg(img) {
    img.style.opacity="0";
}

function mOutImg(img) {
    img.style.opacity="1";
}
```

Now how I can do with all images? I tried anything like this but with bad result.

```
var icone = document.getElementsByClassName("ico");
for (var i=0; i<icone.length; i++){           
    icone[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mOverImg);
    icone[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mOutImg);
}
function mOverImg(e) {                
    e.target.querySelector("img").style.opacity="1";                
}
```

I tried also with:

```
var icone = document.getElementsByClassName("icone");
for (var i=0; i<icone.length; i++){
    var x = document.getElementById(icone[i].getAttribute('id') );
    x.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ mOverImg(x)} );
    x.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ mOoutImg(x)} );
}
```

and this..... :

```
 $(".icone").children().on("mouseover", function(){
     $(this).css("opacity", "1");
 });
```

I can't understand how I have to proceed.

---

Also now I have many many:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph</p>
    <div>Empty</div>
</div>
```

I want to change style to `p` and to empty `div` when `mouseover/mouseout` on container `div`. I tried this and work but I don't want to repeat for all:

```
<div class="container" onmouseover="mOver(b1, p1)" onmouseout="mOut(b1, p1)">
    <p id="p1">Paragraph</p>
    <div id="b1"></div>
</div>

function mOver(obj, p) {
    obj.style.borderColor="white";
    p.style.color="white";
}

function mOut(obj, p) {
   obj.style.borderColor="green";
   p.style.color="#399AF6";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".ico");
x.forEach(function(img){
  img.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ mOverImg(img) });
  img.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){ mOutImg(img) });
});

function mOverImg(img) {
  img.style.opacity="0";
}

function mOutImg(img) {
  img.style.opacity="1";
}
```

```html
<img class="ico" id="n1" alt="one"/>
<img class="ico" id="n2" alt="two"/>
```

As to you second query:

```js
function mOver(thatElement) {
  thatElement.querySelector('#p1').style.color="white";
  thatElement.querySelector('#b1').style.color="white";
}

function mOut(thatElement) {
  thatElement.querySelector('#p1').style.color="green";
  thatElement.querySelector('#b1').style.color="green";
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onmouseover="mOver(this)" onmouseout="mOut(this)">
    <p id="p1">Paragraph</p>
    <div id="b1">Empty</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can delete " ; " into function(){ mOutImg(img); });

Comment: @Origin, Yes it is. Finally use which one best suited in your condition.

Comment: Can i have help with the answer in the bottom page? i'm sorry, i'm new and beginner, and i don't know how use well stack overflow

Comment: Thank you. I changed <p id="p1">, <div id="b1"> with <p class>, <div class> and relative queryselector. Now work with all <div class="container> in the page. |o|

Comment: @Origin, good to know that it is working as you expect.......thanks agian.

Answer (score 5):

Just use **CSS** for this...
You can [select](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) all image classes with `.class` and add effect on mouse `enter/leave` with [`:hover`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

```css
.img{
transition:all 0.5s;
width:100px;
}

.img:hover{
opacity:0.2;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img" id="1"/>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img" id="2"/>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img" id="3"/>
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pulpitrock.jpg" class="img" id="4"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code Snippet Demonstration - Vanilla Javascript:**

```js
var icone = document.getElementsByClassName("ico");
for (var i=0; i<icone.length; i++){           
  icone[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    mOverImg(this)
   });           
  icone[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    mOutImg(this)
   });
}

function mOverImg(e) {                
    e.style.opacity="0";                
}

function mOutImg(e) {                
    e.style.opacity="1";                
}
```

```css
.ico {
  transition: .7s;
}
```

```html
<img class="ico" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" id="n1">
<img class="ico" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" id="n2">
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration - jQuery:**

Utilizing the `.hover()` method <sup>[Ref: jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)</sup>

```js
$('.ico').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('opacity', '0');
}, function() {
  $(this).css('opacity', '1');
});
```

```css
.ico {
  transition: .7s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="ico" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" id="n1">
<img class="ico" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" id="n2">
```